# Why taking a slice of an array in rust has to use &?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, slice

I have this code:

```
#[test]
fn slice_out_of_array() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let nice_slice = a[1..]; //why has to borrow?

    assert_eq!([2, 3, 4], nice_slice)
}
```

This code doesn't work and the rustc will actually ask me to add an & in front of the `a[1..]`. I don't understand why the compiler doesn't allow me to write `a[1..]` as I only need to use this array once, and I the ownship of `a` can be transfer to `nice_slice`.

I can just write a `&` and always use it this way, but I really want to understand the mechnism behind it. Please help, and thanks in advance!

I tried to search up array slice online, but everyone seems just use the sytax, I didn't find much material actually explaining it.

I'm expecting a explanation how the rust compiler works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices are [*Dynamically Sized Types (DSTs)*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html), meaning you can only have them behind an indirection such as `&` or `Box` (it does not mean you cannot own them, `Box` is owning).

DSTs are types whose size is not known at compile time, for examples because we don't know at compile time how many items will be in a slice. Because of that, they cannot be without indirection, because the compiler does not know how much space to allocate on the stack. Therefore, you can only use them behind an indirection, where the size of the pointer is known.

Comment: It's not "the size of the pointer", but "size of the data that the pointer addresses".

Comment: @PaulDempsey No, the size of the pointer itself. The size of the data the pointer addresses is not known.

Comment: I am thinking of native pointers, which are typically always a single size on a given CPU architecture (e.g 64 bits).

Comment: @PaulDempsey Pointers to DSTs can be wider than that, but yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes sense to me. This is my understanding from your solution: We need to use the '&' sign to refer the slice to the original item(which compiler knows the size of the item at compile time). Naturally DST just "belongs" to some item(or object), but the DST itself doesn't have ownership to transfer.